# “No such file or directory” on service rabbitmq-server start

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

As `root`, I installed RabbitMQ per the instructions [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html#managing-service). I then did:

```
cd /sbin
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

...and I got...

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  rabbitmq-server.service
Failed to start rabbitmq-server.service: Unit rabbitmq-server.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Linux info:

```
>cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015

>cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

---

**EDIT #1:**
Here's some additional info:

```
>systemctl status rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

**EDIT #2**
More info:

```
>rpm -qa | grep rabbitmq
>
```

(basically no output)

Here's how I installed, per the instructions [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html#managing-service) on Package Cloud installation.

For erlang:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/erlang/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

For rabbitmq:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

Comment: I strongly suggest asking this question on the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) . The RMQ core team (myself included) monitors the list. It's much easier to discuss there than on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you ran install and configure the repos. You don't appear to have installed the package. No output from

> rpm -qa | grep rabbitmq

is also a clue.

Try installing them with

```
yum install rabbitmq-server erlang
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this. Ran into a problem with the erlang installation. It wants a newer version of openssl. *Sigh*. Hunting that down.

Comment: I upgraded openssl. Then tried `yum install erlang`. Ran into a dependency problem there. I've posted the new problem here: https://serverfault.com/questions/971955/erlang-install-error-requires-libcrypto-so-10openssl-1-0-264bit

Comment: For those interested, the successful recipe for upgrading openssl in my case was: https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-centos-6-centos-7/