# erlang install error: "Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)"

Tags: rhel7

I'm trying to get erlang installed so I can installed rabbitMQ. Here's my sequence and error:

```
>yum install erlang
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:22.0.4-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) for package: erlang-22.0.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: erlang-22.0.4-1.el7.x86_64 (rabbitmq_erlang)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My linux info is:

```
>cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015

>cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

>cat /etc/*elease
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.2 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.2"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.2:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.2"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

...and here's my `openssl` info:

```
>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019
```

Where can I find and install `libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any good reason not to upgrade to latest 7.x?

Comment: Hi, @PatrickMevzek. Thanks for your help. Sorry to be dense. I'm not sure what I'm doing. 7.x of what? And where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RHEL server does not have an active subscription, but [this is required to install packages](https://serverfault.com/a/537570/126632). You need to [register the system](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273) using `subscription-manager register` and an existing or new entitlement. If you haven't got a Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription, you will need to purchase one.

Once your system is properly subscribed, the warning message will no longer appear when you run `yum` and you will be able to install packages.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This is just a dev virtual server spun up to test rabbitMQ. Is there any way to acquire the needed dependencies without going through a subscription process?

Comment: Try using CentOS instead of RHEL in this case. Or ask whoever in your IT department manages your company's RHEL subscriptions if they have an option they can give you. For instance, they could issue activation keys for such virtual machines and then unregister them after a few weeks or when they're no longer needed.

Comment: The end of the answer in your first link says Centos avoids the problem. I thought I was using Centos currently. Am I not? How can I tell? Sorry again for being so dense.

Comment: You showed this information right in your question! `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: I'm just confused because this Q&A shows RHEL also, but they're talking Centos. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54987/how-to-determine-centos-version . Ah, well...unix flavors always are so indirect.

Comment: Anywhere I can get the desired file from a 3rd party location?

Comment: @JonathanM In that question, the accepted answer is unfortunately wrong. Your options are to subscribe your system or use CentOS instead.

Comment: Once I get registered, how do I get the file? Please add that to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanM `yum install erlang`